# how to concatenate two rows in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, string-concatenation

```
   public void ReserveTimeList(){ 
    String sql = "select to_char(to_char(start_time,'HH24:MI') ||' - '|| 
    to_char(end_time,'HH24:MI')) from register_table";
    try {
        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

             //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
           //  dlm.addElement(format.parseObject(rs.getString("time")));

   dlm.addElement(rs.getString("to_char(to_char(start_time,'HH24:MI') ||' - 
   '|| to_char(end_time,'HH24:MI'))"));
            lstResTime.setModel(dlm);
        }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Time_Setting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
       null, ex);
      }

    }
```

The program is correct but i don't know what's the problem,
When I run the program the Exception arias :java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Comment: try to use `rs.getString(1)` instead.

Comment: in rs.getString() you can put your column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an alias, e.g. `my_time`

```
String sql = "select to_char(to_char(start_time,'HH24:MI') ||' - '|| 
    to_char(end_time,'HH24:MI')) as my_time from register_table";
 //...

 dlm.addElement(rs.getString("my_time"))l
```

Comment: or maybe even just select the two date columns directly and do the formatting in Java code.